# Activity to unload a Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm new to WF4 and I was trying to find a way to unload a workflow in a code activity but all I can get in the code activity is the Workflow Instance ID and I don't know how to use the ID to unload a workflow.

Ideally, the workflow would pause for user intervention (this is where I would persist and unload the workflow) and when the user makes the required changes I would want to load the workflow back and continue it. This is a for a WCF WF Service.

Any suggestions and advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a workflow unloading doesn't really make sense, after all the result of the action would update the workflow status and thus invalidate the saved status.

Normally you just create bookmarks in a workflow, and optionally persist the state, and let the runtime environment decide if a workflow needs to be unloaded or not. The way this works depends on the runtime, WorkflowApplication versus WorkflowServiceHost, and is either callback based or idle duration based.

Comment: Oh, I've only glanced at Bookmarks. Does one have to just create a bookmark (in an activity for instance) to pause the workflow? Right now I created a test workflow where I persist it and call another operation passing the correlation variable to use the same instance. Would simply persisting and using a correlation handle work or would Bookmarks be preferred? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Bookmarks are **the** way to get a workflow to become idle in a persistable/unloadable way. Activities like a Delay or Receive all use a bookmark internally.

Comment: Ahh... I'll look into it a bit more. Cheers!